# Confused about variable assignment and definition AngularJS JavaScript Node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to create my own game using the latest JavaScript, AngularJS, and Node.js implementations.

I am basing my code to handle users and players by following the code here:
        https://github.com/amirrajan/nodejs-against-humanity

I notice that gameId and playerId are used as the arguments to most server.js and game.js functions.  To me, this seems appropriate.

I am trying to understand how the playerID is assigned to each player.  There is no Player class that defines/maintains this variable.

Where is the playerID assigned to each player ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common attribute of node.js / javascript apps. Though it is definitely possible to define classes in javascript, data is often passed around in the form of JSON objects. I'm not sure which way that sample app does it, but it might very likely be JSON. For example, player might be a JSON object like this:

```
{
    id: 121525,
    name: "New Player",
    etc: ....
}
```

There therefore may not be a class specifically defining anything. If that sample is made well, it will have some kind of model / class file for a player with methods such as setName(), subtractCash(), or whatever makes sense for a player in that game, but it might not.

The data might be stored in a database and, when retrieved from the database, be loaded into a JSON object in memory that can be passed around. This can trip up coders who move to javascript from other languages that are not loosely typed, like c# / Java.

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  So, in this line here from server.js:  
      game = Game.joinGame(game, { id: req.body.playerId, name: req.body.playerName });  
The 'player' seems to be defined implicitly in that one line and the joinGame function seems to accept the two attributes as 'player' in its parameters ?  So, 'player' is defined in-line in the joinGame function and used as such ?

Comment: My pleasure. I see what's going on there. Yes, player is being passed in to joinGame with an arbitrarily defined JSON object "{ id: req.body.playerId, name: req.body.playerName }". If you look at line 76 that JSON object is added to an array of JSON objects called "players": game.players.push(joiningPlayer); Players was created on line 41 like this: game.players = []; As you can see, it's pretty loosely constructed. A blank array is created (and it can hold anything really: strings, ints, or JSON objects), and JSON objects are added to it to track the players (without any classes).